# SQL Query - How to remove null and replace with blank

Tags: sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ename, sal, comm
FROM EMP
WHERE comm IS NULL
ORDER BY sal DESC;
```

I would like to replace the `NULL` result in the `comm` column with a blank space. I have been told to under `SELECT, write NULL(comm,' ')`, however this comes up with an error, saying invalid number. The query works if I have `NULL(comm, 0)`, returning with 0 in the column.

From my understanding this means I can only have a number value in this column, however I want the blank space. Is someone able to please give me some guidance?

Comment: Am using SQL Developer, if that helps.

Comment: SQL = Structured Query Language - not a product - what **database system** are you using? Does "SQL Developer" imply Oracle??

Comment: SQL Developer is an Oracle product.

Comment: `Oracle SQL Developer` is an Oralce product.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer can be used to connect databases other than Oracle rdbms...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to output space/blank from a query, and if you are using Oracle (as your SQL Developer reference suggest), then you need to use the `NVL()` function with `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT ename, sal, NVL( TO_CHAR(comm), ' ' ) comm
FROM   EMP
WHERE  comm IS NULL
ORDER  BY sal DESC;
```

The `TO_CHAR()` is needed to convert a `NUMBER` to a `VARCHAR2` to make it coompatible with the blank (that is some kind of character value, probably stored as `VARCHAR2` internally). This allows you to avoid "invalid number" error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE EMP SET `ename`='' WHERE `ename` IS NULL
```

And i think, you have repeat this query for each column in your table.

Comment: I don't think we need to UPDATE. Check the above answer by TGH.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
SELECT coalesce(Comm,'') FROM EMP WHERE comm IS NULL ORDER BY sal DESC
```

Comment: `ISNULL` is not an Oracle keyword; the OP stated that he is using SQL Developer that indicates Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: This should work according to http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php

Comment: Yes, indeed, but `NVL()` seems to be more appropriate in this context.

Comment: And `TO_CHAR()` is still needed to avoid 'ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR'.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBJECT, DESCRIPTION, NVL(A.FILENAME,' ') AS FILENAME, 
            to_char(CREATEDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS CURRDATE, STATUS,  
            ASSIGNTO FROM RQST_DETAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query

select ename, ISNULL(comm ,' ') AS comm ,sal from EMP ORDER BY sal desc

it will replace null values with blank of comm column

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, run `DESCRIBE EMP` and post the result to the question. In the result output of the query that you have run press CTRL-A CTRL-SHIFT-C and paste that to the question. That will paint a better picture of what you have achieved and how you want it changed.

Finally you can run the following SQL to verify the version of Oracle that you are running

```
select * from v$version
```

You should see something like this

```
BANNER
Personal Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

If this does not work then SQL Developer may not be connecting to an Oracle DB. Out of the box SQL Developer only connect to Oracle DBs and MS Access ??

And finally to answer your actual question the NVL function substitutes null vales with the second parameter passed to it.

Here a space.

```
SELECT ename, sal, NVL(TO_CHAR(comm),' ')
FROM EMP
WHERE comm IS NULL
ORDER BY sal DESC;
```

Comment: This will result in 'ORA-01722: invalid number'. The number need to be converted to character data first to make it compatible with the blanks.

Comment: Hence the request for DESC EMP :) I didn't have the schema to hand. I'll update the SQL to make it work.

Comment: This table seems to be from the original version (pre-11g) of the `HR` sample schema; was not it familiar from the early days of your database hacking? ;-)

Comment: It was but that was a looooooong time ago :) haha!

Answer (score 0):

If the column is not a string, you could first cast it and then use the isnull

```
select isnull(cast(columnname as varchar(102)),'') as XYZ
```