# Converting null values to blank space in sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have few columns in sql table which are nchar(44) and the value is null but i need white space in them I have  a client requirment  like

```
Poc1 * 45;
Poc2 * 45;
Poc3 * 45;.....poc24 * 45
```

I have same columns data which has null in them when i run the sql query on these columns i should get blank spaces of length 45 each exported to text file. can this be possible.

```
string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
",left([POC1]+'    ',44)" +
",left([POC2]+'    ',44)" +
",left([POC3]+'    ',44)" +
",[t_vrm] " +
",left([POC4]+'    ',44)" +
",left([POC5]+'    ',44)" +
",[t_zone_name]" +
",left([POC6]+'         ',44)" +
",[t_date_time_issued] " +
",left([POC7]+'         ',44)" +
",left([POC8]+'   ',44)" +
",left([POC9]+'   ',44)" +
",left([POC10]+'  ',44)" +
",left([POC11]+'  ',44)" +
",left([POC12]+'  ',44)" +
",left([POC13]+'  ',44)" +
",left([POC14]+'  ',44)" +
",left([POC15]+ '  ',44)" +
",left([POC16]+ '  ',44)" +
```

Comment: `NULL` isn't the same logically as ' ' even though I don't know your environment or application I tend to advise against this.

Comment: If your datatype is `NCHAR(44)` what is the purpose of `LEFT([POCN], 44)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=replace+null+sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507300 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613714

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query - How to remove null and replace with blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696173/sql-query-how-to-remove-null-and-replace-with-blank)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISNULL function:

```
...
,left(ISNULL([POCN], '')+'    ',44)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with both MSSQL and Oracle use COALESCE

```
COALESCE(MyNullColumn, '')
```

You could manually put 45 spaces in the single quotes!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Sql Server that treats nulls and nil as equivalent:

```
set concat_null_yields_null [on|off]
```

Don't use it. If you write standards-compliant SQL with respect to nullity using

- `coalesce(foo,'')`
- `is [not] null`

and the like, your code will work regardless of settings.